# How do hive and drill integrate?

Tags: hive, mapr, shark-sql, apache-drill

Drill looks like an interesting tool for the ad-hoc drill down queries as opposed to the high-latency Hive.
It seems that there should be a decent integration between those two but i couldn't find it.
Lets assume that today all of my work is done on Hive/Shark how can i integrate it with Drill?
Do I have to switch to the Drill engine back and forth?
I'm looking for an integration similar to what Shark and Hive have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are provisions to implement Drill-Hive integration, your question seems to be a bit "before the time" thing. Drill still has a long way to go and folks have been trying really hard to get all this done as soon as possible.

As per their roadmap, Drill will first support Hadoop FileSystem implementations and HBase. Second, Hadoop-related data formats will be supported (eg, Apache Avro, RCFile). Third, MapReduce-based tools will be provided to produce column-based formats. Fourth, Drill tables can be registered in HCatalog. Finally, Hive is being considered as the basis of the DrQL implementation.

See **[this](http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/DrillProposal)** for more details.